# Could not convert value 'System.Collections.ArrayList' to property 'Specialisation'

Tags: solrnet

I am getting Error:-**Could not convert value 'System.Collections.ArrayList' to property 'Specialisation' of document type IKnowWhoKnowsSolrNet**

**MyCode**

```
//Initialise the solrNet Client.
        var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<IKnowWhoKnowsSolrNet>>();

        //Get the data from the ID.
        var results = solr.Query(new SolrQueryByField("id", userName));//Error Place.

        //Check the name is empty or not.
        if (results.Count != 0)
        {
            //assign the areaSpecialisation value.
            areaSpecialisation = results[0].Specialisation;
        }
```

I am getting error here *var results = solr.Query(new SolrQueryByField("id", userName));*

Its working fine if i check with the *userName = bhagirathi* but now changed the username to **userName = 123|bhagirathi|bhagi@abc.com**

Its giving error.

[EDIT]

## region Properties

```
[SolrUniqueKey("id")]
public string UserName { get; set; }

[SolrField("features")]
public string Specialisation { get; set; }

#endregion

#region Constractor

public IKnowWhoKnowsSolrNet()
{
    //
    // TODO: Add constructor logic here
    //
}

/// <summary>
/// Set the class property's value
/// </summary>
/// <param name="userDetails"></param>
/// <param name="areaSpecialisation"></param>
public IKnowWhoKnowsSolrNet(string userName, string areaSpecialisation)
{
    UserName = userName;
    Specialisation = areaSpecialisation;
}

#endregion
```

Id is string in the solr.

[/EDIT]

Please Help
why this error is coming by simply changing the searching query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show how you have the IKnowWhoKnowsSolrNet class defined (especially the Specialisation property) as well as the how the corresponding field is defined in your Solr schema.xml file? This error may be related to the search results being returned and not being able to be mapped to your class correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Is `features` in your solr schema.xml multiValued? If so `Specialisation` in `IKnowWhoKnowsSolrNet` needs to be multivalued too.

```
[SolrField("features")]
public ICollection<string> Specialisation { get; set; }
```